# Kendo Editor snippets and MVVM

Tags: kendo-ui

Is it possible to specify a source for available 'snippets' for the Editor widget. I'd like to put store them in a separate array (or even better, retrieve them from a remote data source).

I've tried something like:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="editor">
  <textarea name="test" data-bind="value:test" data-role="editor" data-tools="['insertHtml']" data-insert-html="snippets"></textarea>
</script>
```

where `snippets` is the array as per the Editor demo, but this doesn't work.

It this supported?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no longer relevant, but for further reference:

```
 <textarea data-role="editor"
   data-tools="['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'justifyLeft', 'justifyCenter', 'justifyRight', 'justifyFull',
   { name: 'insertHtml',
                  items: [{ text: 'title', value: '{{title}}' },
                          { text: 'description' , value: '{{description}}' },
                          { text: 'link' , value: '{{link}}'},
                          { text: 'notes' , value: '{{notes}}'}]
   }]"
   data-bind="value: emailForm.body"></textarea>
```

This allows you to add snippets to the toolbar using the MVVM method. To get them from a remote datasource you most likely need to do this by finding the kendo control when it is rendered and then set a different datasource with a similar key/value structure.